# ASP.NET Session State & Other session Variables

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

I have an ASP Application having In Process State Mode and using cookie for SessionId.
`Time Out = 120 mn`
The issue I am facing is that I am having a session id generated but after some time (random amount of time), I loose session variables but still have the same Session-Id.

Hope I was clear, Thnx

Comment: Your application can be recycled during that time and you  are losing your session variables in this case.
Why not to use session state server?

Comment: No, my application pool is recycled once per day (at 6 am). And i guess i can't change Session State mode actually (the Application is on Production).